# Biblatex: two bibliographies with increasing numbers

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently using `biblatex` to make two bibliographies, using `\printbibliography` and the `keyword` argument. I just label which citation I want in which bibliography using keywords in the `.bib` file. When I do this, the references are sorted and numbered as a whole and then divided between the two bibliographies. This causes numbers to appear in a slightly strange order. Is there a simple way to make the ordering be monotone? Or should I just switch to a non-numeric citation style?

I think a MWE is

```
@article{A,
author={A B},
title={Test 1},
keywords={primary}
}
@article{B,
author={C D},
title={Test 2},
keywords={secondary}
}
@article{C,
author={E F},
title={Test 3},
keywords={primary}
}
```

in a bib file called bibtest.bib, and then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}

\begin{document}

This document is a test \cite{A},\cite{B},\cite{C}.

\printbibliography[title={Primary},keyword={primary}]

\printbibliography[title={Secondary},keyword={secondary}]

\end{document}
```

If sorted by author then the numbers will appear as 1 3 in the primary and 2 in the secondary, whereas I would prefer them to appear as 1 2 in the primary and 3 in the secondary.

Comment: `defernumbers=true`, i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}` should help. Maybe you have to delete all the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`) before you recompile for this to take effect.

Comment: @moewe Perfect. You can make that an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the load-time/global option

```
defernumbers=true
```

i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}`.

With that setting labels are assigned for each of the subbibliographies chronologically.

The default `defernumbers=false` assigns labels based on a global list of references even if that global list is never printed.

Comment: Thank you! Minor suggestion for improving the answer: mention that the option goes in the optional arguments to \usepackage{biblatex}. It's in your comment, of course, but still. (It does not matter for me, since I just used the comment, but it could matter if someone else stumbles on this.)